# Criterion of flatness for projective morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a projective morphism, $\mathcal O(1)$ is a relatively very ample sheaf, then f is flat iff $f_*\mathcal O(m)$ is locally free for big $m$. I can prove flatness implies that $f_*\mathcal O(m)$ is locally free for big $m$, but I have no idea how to prove the other side of the statement.

Comment: Since flatness is affine local on the target, we may as well assume that that $Y$ is affine, say $\text{Spec}(A)$, and $X=\text{Proj}(S_\bullet)$, for $S_\bullet$ some graded $A$-algebra. This then says that $S_{m\bullet}$ is $A$-flat for sufficiently large $m$. You need to show that $((S_{\bullet})_f)_0$ is flat for all homogenous $f$ which are not nilpotent. It seems like you can probably "push" individual elements into high enough degree so you're in the realm of $S_{m\bullet}$ by pushing things to the denominator. Something like that?

Comment: Also, it seems as though you could probably just easily solve this by observing that the condition implies that the Veronese subring $S_{m\bullet}$ is flat over the base, and then using the fact that $\text{Proj}(S_{m\bullet})\cong \text{Proj}(S_\bullet)$.